# Knots in restricted cubic splines as free parameters or pre-assigned?

Tags: splines

On p. 26 of *Regression Modelling Strategies* (2nd ed.) Frank Harrell argues against letting the knots in a RCS be free parameters and for setting them in advance, at various quintiles.

He cites several reasons including instability of estimates, inference problems and a lack of software.

I was wondering if this is still true? That is, have there been developments in algorithms and software that alleviate some or all of these problems?